# How to get the text from the Button when clicked?

Tags: android, button, android-widget

```
for( i=0; i<26; i++)    {
    
    btnAlpha[i] = new Button(this);
    btnAlpha[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    btnAlpha[i].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    btnAlpha[i].setText(Character.toString ((char)(j+i)));
    btnAlpha[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){              
        public void onClick(View v){
        //Want to get the text from the current button.
                         btnAlpha[i].getText();
                        //But it gives error that "i" cannot be accessed.
            
    }});
```

I get the error "cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method". But I need to get the text at that right time. How to do it? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Button is a subclass of View, so the argument to onClick, v, is the Button being clicked. Try

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((Button) v).getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new variable `final int x = i;` in the for loop and use `x` in place of `i` in the `onClick` method

edit: actually im not sure this will work correctly. oops.  Kype P's answer looks pretty good.