# Android: Dynamically create image button with click event

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I require to have a list of image buttons in an activity which are created based on the data in a database. I haven't created anything like this in android before and so far I've been using HTML tables to show my data in a grid view. I'm not asking for any special code, I'm just clueless on how to implement this. I wanna know what the best approach is.

One problem I've faced is with the click events(in the way I've been doing them so far) which do not take in any EventArg, so I can't get the name of the button out of them.

Comment: This helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106198/androidhow-to-get-the-text-from-the-button-when-clicked?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that the OnClickListener instance is applied to a Button, then you could just cast the received view to a Button and get the text:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        // 1) Possibly check for instance of first 
        Button b = (Button)v;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

// create the layout params that will be used to define how your button will be displayed

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

// Create Button

```
final Button btn = new Button(this);
```

// Give button an ID

```
btn.setId(someinteger);
btn.setText("Add Text");
```

// set the layoutParams on the button

```
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Lets say I have to use a single event to get their text, how can this part be done, this was my main question